# Delete Sun ONE ldap account with dn encoded in base64

Tags: ldap, base64

I have a Sun ONE ldap account the dn of which accidentally became base64-encoded after an rdn change.  I have tried various ways to delete this account to no avail.   I hope there are people here who know a solution and able help me out.

On the Sun ONE ldap server all attributes are encoded in ascii.  The attribute used as rdn is uid.  The format of uid for user accounts is FIRSTNAME.LASTNAME.

The uid of the account in question was YAZAIRA.DAZ.  A utility written in unix shell was used to change the rdn of the account from YAZAIRA.DAZ to YAZAIRA.DIAZ.  The utility prompts for both the old uid and the new uid, and takes care of everything else under the hood to get the rdn changed.  At the time, the new uid was copied from another system and pasted at the prompt to the utility, which contained a non-ascii character: YAZAIRA.DÍAZ (notice the ' on top of I).

Therefore, under the hood, the ldif was

```
dn: uid=YAZAIRA.DAZ,OU=People,dc=company,dc=com
change-type: modrdn
newrdn: uid=YAZAIRA.DÍAZ
deleteoldrdn: 1
```

After the ldif was run, ldapsearch was not able to find the account.  Luckily, after many tries, the account entry was eventually returned as one of several when uid=YAZAIRA.* was entered as search criteria.  However, its dn is:

```
dn:: dWlkPVlBWkFJUkEuRM1BWixvdT1QZW9wbGUsZGM9Y29tcGFueSxkYz1jb20=
```

and all the attributes that contains the new last name are base64 encoded too.

I want to delete this account using ldapdelete with the accompanying file containing the dn. So far I have tried the following dn, but none has worked:

```
dWlkPVlBWkFJUkEuRM1BWixvdT1QZW9wbGUsZGM9Y29tcGFueSxkYz1jb20=
uid=YAZAIRA.DIAZ,OU=People,dc=company,dc=com
uid=YAZAIRA.DÍAZ,OU=People,dc=company,dc=com
uid=cWUFaQUlSQS5EzUFa,OU=People,dc=company,dc=com
uid=YAZAIRA.RM1BWg==,OU=People,dc=company,dc=com
uid=YAZAIRA.*,OU=People,dc=company,dc=com
```

Would appreciate it very much if someone knows how to specify the dn to ldapdelete.  Or if there are some alternative ways to delete an account by uniquely identifying the account using attributes other than the dn.  Or whatever means to get this account deleted.

Comment: The DN is base64 encoded because it contains a non-ascii character, and therefore it's mandatory to base64 encode it when displaying the values in LDIF. Tools like ldapsearch, ldapdelete, ldapmodify will always do that. However if you write a program that read the entry and then delete it by specifying the exact same DN, it should work. This said, I haven't played with Sun One DS for a while.

Comment: I never knew there is such a mechanism in the ldap server.  We never entered anything that is non plain ascii, intentional or accidental, and it is the first time experiencing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried ldapdelete with the following LDIF?

```
dn:: dWlkPVlBWkFJUkEuRM1BWixvdT1QZW9wbGUsZGM9Y29tcGFueSxkYz1jb20=
changetype: delete
-
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  It worked.  I did not think of using ldapmodify but stuck to ldapdelete.  ldapdelete requires the dn without the "dn: " attribute name.  I still wonder what the two colons mean and how to split apart the name and value of the dn attribute.  I did try ": dWlkPVlBWkFJUkEuRM1BWixvdT1QZW9wbGUsZGM9Y29tcGFueSxkYz1jb20=" for ldapdelete but it did not work.  Now using the lumpsum of dn:: dWlkPVlBWkFJUkEuRM1BWixvdT1QZW9wbGUsZGM9Y29tcGFueSxkYz1jb20= with ldapmodify, it worked.  Thank you again!